# saving strike through element to local storage for To Do list

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, web-applications

I'm making a to DO list and am having a hard time understanding how to save the css strike through element into local storage.

**HTML CODE:**

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index"
        class="list-group-item shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded border border-dark rounded" id="myTask">
        <input type="checkbox" (click)='update()'><span>
        {{todo.task}} <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete()">X</button>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Typescript Code:**

```
 update() {
    localStorage.setItem('checkbox', JSON.stringify(this.todos));

  }
```

**CSS Code:**

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+span {
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: red;
  }
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Your code seems fine. what happens when you try to get those items?

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos; let i = index"
        class="list-group-item shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded border border-dark rounded" id="myTask">
        <input type="checkbox" (change)='update()' [(ngModel)]="todo.checked"><span>
        {{todo.task}} <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="delete()">X</button>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Add a property in your todos array item as checked and bind it to the variable using the model and based on the model add the css and store it in the local storage

```
update() {
    localStorage.setItem('checkbox', JSON.stringify(this.todos));

  }
```

Now when you save the todos list it will contain the checked and uncheck one as true and false